# Read/write in the same table

Tags: spring-batch

I have a chunk tasklet in Spring Batch. The processor reads form table A, the writer writes to table A when the record is not present. When I configure the commit-interval to 1, it works fine.

When i configure the commit-interval to a higher number i'm getting dublicate entry execptions because the processor didn't get the dirty read information.

My Tasklet is configured with a read uncommit statement:
`batch:transaction-attributes isolation = "READ_UNCOMMITTED"`

I think that this configurations was not accepted in my configuration? Any ideas?

Comment: You should read using a reader, not a processor

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't encountered this problem because read/process/write are (usually) managed in this manner:

1. read is done in a separate connection
2. chunk write is done in its own transaction for skip/retry/fault management

You don't need to use `READ_UNCOMMITTED` but more easy:

1. Create a `ItemReader<S>` (a `JdbcCursorItemReader` should be fine)
2. Process your item with an `ItemProcessor<S,T>`
3. Write your own `ItemWriter<T>` that write/update an object based on its presence on database

If you want to reduce items to write with your custom writer you can filter out duplicate objects during process phase: you can achive this goal using a map to store duplicated items like described by [@jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101928/jackson-ha) (only for current chunk items, not for all rows in database - this step is done later by `ItemWriter`)

Answer (score -1):

dirty reads in general is a scary idea.

sounds like it is a design issue instead.

what you should be doing is...
1) sounds like you should introduce a cache/map to store entries you plan to commit, but haven't written into db yet.

if the entry is already in table A or in the cache, skip.
if the entry is NOT in table A or the cache, then save a copy into the cache, and add it to the list of candidates to be written by the writer.